# Remove OTP Box Automatically

Tags: javascript, html

i want to remove [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbQiC.jpg)
this OTP Box Automatically using Java script How can I do This ...

or how can i remove

```
<div class="col-32">
                           <input name="reotp" id="reotp" size="50" maxlength="6" type="password">
                        </div>
```

this automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean to hide it. If it so then this snippet will work

```
document.getElementById('reotp').style.display = "none"
```

If you want to remove the DOM then [**removeChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) can be used